# Can't get scripts to run on Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

For some reason the first time I downloaded and installed python, pip was not working. I reinstalled python and set the path of the interpreter on Pycharm, but now when I make a configuration and run, nothing happens. I'm not even able to print a simple Hello World. The console comes up with an exit code of 0, however nothing else happens.

I may have done something wrong while setting up Pycharm, any guidance towards a solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code so that we can see what you are working with.
What if you run `python <filename>`?

Comment: My code consisted of only a print statement to make sure that the interpreter was working correctly. The run button is perfectly fine, but when I click it it exits immmediately and says it exited with a exit code of 0.

Comment: There is probably a bug in your code. Could you please post your code?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pycharm.  Where does it typically display code output?  Is there a separate window/view for that?

Comment: @SolomonUcko the line I was using to test it was just print('Hello, World')

Comment: @DamonLarcom that is probably because Pycharm doesn't execute scripts like that like the python IDLE.

Comment: @JohnGordon it would appear under the run tab in Pycharm. I regularly use IntelliJ for Java, but I cant seem to fix this issue with Pycharm.

Comment: @JerryM. I had Pycharm working like that before, I just tried reinstalling python because pip was not working properly. Ever since then its not worked. Do you have any ideas what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the run button didn't actually run your script. Try entering the following code and clicking the run button next to the first line:

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello, world!')
```

Comment: I had been trying stuff like that for a while and its suddenly working again, thanks!

Comment: @DamonLarcom Glad I could help! You can click the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main():
    print("Hello World")

main()
```

Comment: Still isnt printing anything to the console. I'm fairly confident I did something wrong setting up Pycharm, just not familiar enough with it to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back and had to enable the interactive console to see the output.  The setting should be in "Run/Edit Configurations" under Python's config tab.  Changing the "interpreter options:" to "-i" should enable the interactive console.

The exit code 0 just is telling you the code ran without any errors.